# TypeError: Cannot read property 'CameraType' of undefined, React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-camera

I'm currently using expo-camera for camera features, but the app crashes when it tries to start on android device. Here's my js code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Button} from 'react-native';
import { Camera, CameraType } from 'expo-camera';

export default function CameraComp({ navigation }) {

const [type, setType] = useState(CameraType.back);
...
}
```

When I try to start the app I get the following error: Cannot read property 'CameraType' of undefined. I'm following this tutorial from expo: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/

My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.1"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    }
}
```

Package.json:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^49.0.13",
    "expo-camera": "~13.4.4",
    "expo-modules-core": "^1.5.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.5"
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete code. This has been tested and working fine.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, View, Button, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Camera, CameraType } from "expo-camera";

export default function CameraComp({ navigation }: any) {
  const [type, setType] = useState(CameraType.back);
  const [permission, requestPermission] = Camera.useCameraPermissions();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Permission is granted", permission?.granted);
  }, [permission]);

  const toggleCameraType = async () => {
    setType((current) => (current === CameraType.back ? CameraType.front : CameraType.back));
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Camera Comp {type}</Text>
      <Camera style={styles.camera} type={type} />
      <Button title="Grant Permission" onPress={() => requestPermission()} />
      <Button title="Flip Camera" onPress={toggleCameraType} disabled={permission?.granted ? false : true} />
      <Button title="Go to Home" onPress={() => navigation.push("Home")} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  camera: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 350,
  },
});
```

On pressing "Grant Permission" button, your mobile device  will ask for camera permission. You have to press "Allow" option. Then reload the app again. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

You should add "plugins" block in your app.json file:

```js
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-camera",
        {
          "cameraPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your camera."
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I did that thinking that could be the reason, but I'm still getting the same error..